# Could Thor get himself a new Mjölnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, mjolnir

After Hela destroyed it, would it be possible for him to get a new one? Or was it unique?

Comment: Did you watch the post and mid credit scenes?

Comment: Also, Thor doesn't _need_ the hammer, so who cares?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.** Thor's hammer was [imbued with the Odinforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOIxm.png) in order to complete its enchantments. Within the MCU this also seems to be the case given that Hela was able to destroy it with relative ease after Odin

> died

This event means that the Odinforce is no longer available to make another hammer of the same capacity. This pre-supposes that other power sources such as the [Tesseract](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Tesseract) would be insufficient or inappropriate for the task, which is something that we simply don't know (yet).

You might also want to note that the [time stone](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_of_Agamotto) could theoretically restore Mjolnir to its former glory if Thor went back to Norway to collect the pieces and then gave them to Dr Strange. Again, we don't know what the barriers would be to such a task.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Mjolnir was forged from the heart of a dying star. Thor's mystical hammer Mjolnir, which resembles a mallet rather than a war hammer, has a number of elemental powers. It has been stated by Odin himself that Mjolnir's power has no equal.
- http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir

A new hammer could be forged but there is no guarantee that it would be "equal" in strength or abilities to the original Hammer.

Comment: While the wiki is a good start, it's not the most canonical source, we usually prefer things from the scripts, scenes from the films or comics. With your second paragraph, would the post-credit scene not suggest that Mjölnir is still kicking around?

Comment: Ragnarok had 2 post credit scenes...I don't recall either having anything to do with the hammer.. Can you please explain your comment about it still "kicking around"?

Comment: I almost distinctly recall seeing one where the hammer is flying through space.

Comment: I found a clip of this on youtube, but it wasn't in the theater I went to in Michigan, USA.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBULR4T3mKU

I have no way to verify the authenticity of this video

Comment: Thor is clearly holding a Black Hammer (and has short hair) in this INFINITY WAR marketing...
https://movieweb.com/avengers-infinity-war-vanity-fair-magazine-covers-photos/

Comment: Here's really low quality footage of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IJk9xgmFjE

Comment: Although, I don't really know how accurate this is.

Comment: For the record, it was forged using the *heat* from the heart of a star, not from the stellar material itself.

Comment: The hammer, while cool, was only a focus, a tool for Thor to learn to use his power.  By the end of Ragnarok, he clearly does not need such a crutch any more.  If he wants one, he could always summon one...